# How can I get opinions about a subject that doesn't fit the question-answer format?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm turning over in my mind ideas about exception handling in *Mathematica*. I would like to get opinions about the way I'm approaching the subject, but I find it quite difficult to compress the topic into short question-answer slices.

In any case, doing so would probably disrupt the reading even beyond the desolation created by my poor English.

How can I share a short note I wrote about the topic and ask for suggestions?

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109888/general-strategies-to-write-big-code-in-mathematica) you can find a long discussion of this sort, but it's rather an exception to the too-broad rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that a posting such as you propose risks being closed as too-broad or mainly-opinion-based. However, here are some suggestions:

1. Post it anyway. If the post is intriguing enough to produce a lively discussion in the form of answers, it will probably survive. After all, there are a few precedents for such discussions on our main QA site.
2. Bring it up in chat. The restrictions in chat are looser than on the main QA site.
3. Find another *Mathematica* discussion site that is more friendly to posts soliciting opinions. Wolfram Community maybe?

Comment: My opinion : "bring it up in chat" :  preferably in a special room dedicated to the subject. So if the discussion takes several days, as it is often the case, the relevant informations stay together. But one can also have a discussion without restrictions in these special rooms.

Comment: @andre. I recommend you express your comment here as another answer.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! If I understood them accurately, I could resort to chat for the main aim, and ask some delimited questions in the main site, referring to the dedicated room ...

Answer (score 6):

My opinion :

It's a good idea to bring the subject up in chat, preferably in a special room dedicated to the subject. So if the discussion takes several days, as it is often the case, the relevant informations stay together. But one can also have a discussion without restrictions in these dedicated rooms.

Maybe the problem with these rooms is that they are not visited by a lot of people.

Dedicated rooms can also be freezed for inactivity,  but they are still readable years after.

(feel free to correct my english)